# How can I get rendered text of any HTML in ExtJS?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

**There is a HTML which saved in a textareafield;**

```
"<pre class="brush: sql"><span style="color:#999;">SELECT </span>ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER.MSG_ID,ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER.MSG
 <span style="color:#999;">FROM </span>ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER</pre>"
```

**I want to get this;**

> SELECT
>   ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER.MSG_ID,ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER.MSG  FROM ATM.TBL_SKR_LISTENER

How can I get rendered value of this HTML code with using ExtJS ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's rather simple, just create div and set innerHTML of this div to textarea value, then get textContent or innerText of the div. See this fiddle for more details: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/c1f

Comment: Yes, It works!
I used textareafield again and set its value to created div's innerHTML. 
Thank you